# GCD flow how to write

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to make screen shot of avplayer when video start playing so i need to run this code in fast in background so it will not block main thread and other controls run fast simultaneous,trying to run that code GCD format i am not able to run please help me to do that it stops at where i add into my array(in array i am adding UIImage Object)...

```
if (isCaptureScreenStart)
{
    if (CMTimeGetSeconds([avPlayer currentTime])>0)
    {
        if (avFramesArray!=nil)
        {
            queue = dispatch_queue_create("array", NULL);
            dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
                [avFramesArray addObject:[self screenshotFromPlayer:avPlayer maximumSize:avPlayerLayer.frame.size :CMTimeGetSeconds([avPlayer currentTime])]];//stop at this line
                NSLog(@"count:%d",[avFramesArray count]);
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSLog(@"Frame are created:%d",[avFramesArray count]);
                    if ([avFramesArray count]==0)    
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Frame are over");
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
dispatch_release(queue);
```

---

Edit:

I think i need to use `dispatch_group_async` this block now..please give some guideline that how to use:

```
if (isCaptureScreenStart)
{
    if (CMTimeGetSeconds([avPlayer currentTime])>0)
    {
        if (avFramesArray!=nil) {
            dispatch_group_async(serial_group1, serial_dispatch_queue1, ^{
                [avFramesArray addObject:[self screenshotFromPlayer:avPlayer maximumSize:avPlayerLayer.frame.size :CMTimeGetSeconds([avPlayer currentTime])]];
            });
        }
    }
    dispatch_group_notify(serial_group1, serial_dispatch_queue1, ^{
        NSLog(@"task competed");
    });
}
```

Now I am using this block but above execution is contentious running and if i use `dispatch_suspend(serial_dispatch_queue1);` its stop but again i need to start block execution then what i need to use i have also try with `dispatch_resume(serial_dispatch_queue1);` again load but system show me crash

Comment: dispatch_group how i need to Create?? and how to use tell steps or any example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dispatch_release(queue);` don't do it there, the dispatch queue that you are calling its going to a backThread, so wat is happening is :-

> your queue is getting released before the block of code executes.

since your `queue` looks like an ivar, release it in dealloc. Rest, your code looks fine ..put a breakpoint inside and check if the block is executing.

**EDIT**

I dont understand, what u are trying to achieve by suspending the queue, there is no need to do it. You dont need to check whether the block has finished executing. The block will finish and then call the `dispatch_async` , get the main queue and update the UI from there.

Now, when you are creating the queue, create it lazily in your method. take the queue as an ivar in header file:

```
@interface YourFileController : UIViewController {
    dispatch_queue_t queue;
}
```

Then in your method modify it as such:

```
if (isCaptureScreenStart)
{
    if (CMTimeGetSeconds([avPlayer currentTime])>0)
    {
        if (avFramesArray!=nil)
        {
            if (!queue)
                queue = dispatch_queue_create("array", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

            dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
                [avFramesArray addObject:[self screenshotFromPlayer:avPlayer maximumSize:avPlayerLayer.frame.size :CMTimeGetSeconds([avPlayer currentTime])]];//stop at this line
                NSLog(@"count:%d",[avFramesArray count]);
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSLog(@"Frame are created:%d",[avFramesArray count]);
                    if ([avFramesArray count]==0)    
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Frame are over");
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE** : `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` creates a serial queue, meaning all the blocks submitted to it will execute serially in First in First Out order. Once all the blocks submitted get executed, the queue stays ;) ..submit another block to it and it executes the block :D

this represents one whole block:-

```
[avFramesArray addObject:[self screenshotFromPlayer:avPlayer maximumSize:avPlayerLayer.frame.size :CMTimeGetSeconds([avPlayer currentTime])]];//stop at this line
                NSLog(@"count:%d",[avFramesArray count]);
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSLog(@"Frame are created:%d",[avFramesArray count]);
                    if ([avFramesArray count]==0)    
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Frame are over");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks i had removed dispatch_release(queue); also my block gets executing.. but my code gets stop on this Line **dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{** and it does not process anything also can you tell that how to check that block is completed or not and Where i am going wrong

Comment: do this instead `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ` You are calling the block on main queue synchronously, which is blocking the main thread `_async` will get the main queue asynchronously and :) ..you will be done

Comment: yes correct 100 points given to u..:) NSLog(@"Thanks"); and also i am calling that method in NSTimer But now how i am going to check that **my block is completed or not**

Comment: I think i need to use **dispatch_group_async** this block now..please give some guideline that how to use

Comment: if (isCaptureScreenStart)
    {
        if (CMTimeGetSeconds([avPlayer currentTime])>0)
        {
            if (avFramesArray!=nil)
            {
                dispatch_group_async(serial_group1, serial_dispatch_queue1, ^{
  [avFramesArray addObject:[self screenshotFromPlayer:avPlayer  maximumSize:avPlayerLayer.frame.size :CMTimeGetSeconds([avPlayer currentTime])]];
                });
            }
        }
        dispatch_group_notify(serial_group1, serial_dispatch_queue1, ^{
            NSLog(@"task competed");
        });
    }

Comment: Now I am using this block but above execution is contentious running and if i use ** dispatch_suspend(serial_dispatch_queue1);** its stop but again i need to start block execution then what i need to use i have also try with**dispatch_resume(serial_dispatch_queue1);** again load but system show me crash

Comment: @Rob i Have Multiple action Running same time so i need to use that because i had try with **dispatch_sync** with this format, but other controls are running slow So i am going with now**dispatch_group_async**.I can not remove from array until my video is getting created So once i will get all images in array (Which is Screen capturing code) then i merge that frame with video and create new video then my array gets nil I know it will create me memory issues but still i am trying to removing way out on this